# Check an user is exist or not in RegisterController Laravel and redirect back to registration page

Tags: php, laravel

How to redirect back in laravel default authentication system.For example in Auth\RegisterController

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'contact_no' => 'required|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
           ]);
    }

protected function create(array $data)

{
    $email = $data['email'];
    $token = $data['token'];

    $checkUser = Invitation::where('email', $email)
        ->where('token', $token)
        ->first();

    if (!$checkUser) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Credentials not matched !');
    }

   return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'contact_no' => $data['contact_no'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
       ]);
```

before creating an user i want to check the user is exist or not with a token came from another table.I checkuser with a query and if i use this before the create method ,

```
if (!$checkUser) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Credentials not matched !');
}
```

it throws an error

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse given,
```

problem occurred with the redirect inside the if condition.If i dd('error') inside if it shows error when check user return null

Comment: We need to see the full controller code.

Comment: The Auth controller would automatically do this for you. It won't register two users with the same email address.

Comment: Why not just use [Validator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation)? `'email' => 'required|email|unique:users'`?

Comment: I used validator.,but here is a different scenario.I edit my code, see above.

Comment: You likely didn't get this error from this code you posted

Comment: Is it ok to check only with the `token` ?? or only with the mail ?

Comment: User send an invitation and if admin accept , a token is generated and saved in invitation table .So before registration I need to check that the user invitation is accepted by the admin,i mean user is valid for sign up.

Comment: Do you have `Authenticatable` on your `User` model ?. Please post your complete model & controller files.

Comment: Yes i have the Authenticatable  in my user model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a change in if condition in   protected function create(array $data) in RegisterController

```
 if (!$checkUser) {
            return null;
        }
```

and overwrite the register method from trait RegistersUsers in RegisterController

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        $user = $this->create($request->all());

        if(!$user) return redirect()->back()->with('error','Credentials Not Matched! ');

        event(new Registered($user));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
            ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **isset** to check if a user exists.

```
if (!isset($checkUser)) {
     return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Credentials not matched !');
}
```

And lastly, I recommend using [Laracasts/Flash](https://github.com/laracasts/flash) for a more fluent flash messaging. So your code would be something like this.

```
flash()->error('Credentials not matched.');
return redirect()->back();
```

To sum up my suggestion:

```
if (!isset($checkUser)) {
     flash()->error('Credentials not matched.');
     return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: Issue with the redirect not with the query checking

Answer (score 0):

You can add your logic in the `validator` method of the `RegisterController` like this :

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    \Validator::extend('has_invitation', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) use($data){
        $checkUser = Invitation::where('email', $data['email'])
                                ->where('token', $value)
                                ->first();
        return !$checkUser; 
    }, "Credentials not matched !");

    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'token' => 'required|has_invitation'
    ]);
}
```

If there is an error in validation laravel will automaticly redirect to the registration page.

Comment: What do you get ??

Comment: Its not working and user registered if he not present in invitation table.

Comment: Can you add `dd($checkUser);` just before `return !$checkUser;` to check what happening. What do you get ?